# Get the most popular result from theses tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my table definition:

**Table ___Rooms:**

```
|--------|-----------|--------|----------|
|ROO_Id  |ROO_HotelId|ROO_Name|ROO_Number|
|--------|-----------|--------|----------|
|       1|AAA00      |Room 12 |        12|
|       2|AAA00      |Room 14 |        14|
|       3|AAA00      |Room 16 |        16|
|       4|ZZZ99      |Room 11 |        11|
|       5|ZZZ99      |Room 22 |        22|
|       6|ZZZ99      |Room 33 |        33|
|--------|-----------|--------|----------|
```

**Table ___Bookings:**

```
|--------|-----------|----------|
|BOO_Id  |BOO_HotelId|BOO_RoomId|
|--------|-----------|----------|
|       1|AAA00      |         1|
|       2|AAA00      |         1|
|       3|AAA00      |         3|
|       4|ZZZ99      |         5|
|       5|ZZZ99      |         5|
|       6|ZZZ99      |         5|
|--------|-----------|----------|
```

Actually, I have:

- Number of booking for `AAA00` = 3
- Number of rooms for `AAA00` = 3

---

I want to list rooms for the property `AAA00` only and rank them by the most popular in them of number of bookings.

So I use this query:

```
SELECT r.ROO_Number BOO_RoomId, 
  ( ( ifnull(cnt_book,0)*100)/(SELECT count(*) FROM ___Bookings)) percentage, 
  ifnull(cnt_book,0) `count` 
FROM ___Rooms r 
   LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT BOO_RoomId, count(*) cnt_book 
               FROM ___Bookings 
               WHERE BOO_HotelId='AAA00' 
               GROUP BY BOO_RoomId
             ) cnt ON r.ROO_Id=cnt.BOO_RoomId 
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

The expecting result of this query was:

- ## 1 - Room 2 - 2 bookings - 66.66%
- ## 2 - Room 3 - 1 booking -  33.33%
- ## 3 - Room 2 - 0 booking -  00.00$

But it returns me all the rooms.

Could you please help me with that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Use `CASE` with `SUM` to add together all bookings per room. Then, `JOIN` to subquery to make the hotel total-bookings available to every row.

```
SELECT r.ROO_Name
     , Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) NumBookings
     , Concat(
         Format(
           Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
           / TotalBookings 
           * 100
         , 0)
       , '%') AS PercentageTotal
  FROM (  __Rooms r LEFT JOIN __Bookings b ON r.ROO_Id = b.BOO_RoomId
       ) INNER JOIN (SELECT BOO_HotelId
                          , Count(*) AS TotalBookings
                       FROM __Bookings 
                      GROUP BY BOO_HotelId
                    ) AS TotalHotelBookings 
                 ON r.ROO_HotelId = TotalHotelBookings.BOO_HotelId
 WHERE r.ROO_HotelId = 'AAA00'
 GROUP BY r.ROO_Name
 ORDER BY r.ROO_Name
;
```

#### Result Set

```
ROO_Name  NumBookings  PercentageTotal
--------  -----------  ---------------
Room 12             2              67%
Room 14             0               0%
Room 16             1              33%
```

#### Key point

`Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`

Comment: Hum... Thanks but I have this error : `Warning: Division by zero`.

Comment: I think if because `TotalBookings` returns me 0 with some datas in my real database. How can I have a condition in this case please ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    foo.ROO_Id,
    foo.ROO_Name, 
    foo.cnt, 
    (foo.cnt * 100.0) / (SELECT count(*) FROM ___Bookings WHERE BOO_HotelId = foo.ROO_HotelId) AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROO_Id,
        ROO_Name,
        ROO_HotelId,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM ___Bookings b WHERE b.BOO_RoomId = r.ROO_Id) AS cnt
    FROM ___Rooms r
    WHERE ROO_HotelId = 'AAA00'
) AS foo
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: The query works just fine on PostgreSQL. If you are getting 100% everywhere it must be some rounding issue. Try **CAST(count(*) * 100.0 AS float)** or adding parentheses.